# Sign In With Google: popup_blocked_by_browser (Angular application)

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-signin, angular-social-login, angular13

I am trying to use Google SSO in my application. For this purpose I am successfully using [angularx-social-login](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) library.

However I would also like to use the google buttons explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) (Sign In With Google).

However, the following issue arises. When the user click the login button and then log in with his google account, the following error is thrown by the browser (Chrome): "popup_blocked_by_browser".

It seems that it occurs because I am calling also my backend during the procedure and thus the popup is blocked because the browser reckon that it was not open by the user.

Could you help to find a solution for this problem?

Here the code:

```
<!-- login-component.html -->

<div id="g_id_onload"
   data-client_id="dummyClientCode"
   data-callback="googleLogin"
   data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin"
   data-type="standard"
   data-size="large"
   data-theme="outline"
   data-text="sign_in_with"
   data-shape="rectangular"
   data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

// login-component.ts
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from 
'@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  // the parent component shall perform api call
  @Output() login = new EventEmitter<null>(); 

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    (window as any).googleLogin = this.login.emit.bind(this);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, New Client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 can use the older Google Platform Library. By default, newly created Client IDs are now blocked from using the Platform Library and instead must use the newer Google Identity Services library. You may choose any value, a descriptive name such as product or plugin name is recommended for easy identification.

Example: **plugin_name**: 'login'.

Please Read my article [Angular 14 Login with Google using OAuth 2.0](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) where I explained everything step by step.

```
googleAuthSDK() {

    (<any>window)['googleSDKLoaded'] = () => {
      (<any>window)['gapi'].load('auth2', () => {
        this.auth2 = (<any>window)['gapi'].auth2.init({
          client_id: 'YOUR CLIENT ID',
          plugin_name:'login',
          cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
          scope: 'profile email'
        });
        this.callLogin();
      });
    }
```